# Unable to push file from local repository to Github.... it just hangs

Tags: github

I have created a local repository "`Python_programming_notes`".
I have created a sample `README.md` file in it initially.
I have created a repository in my GitHub account with the same name "`Python_programming_notes`".

If i try to move this `README.md` file to GitHub repository, the cursor just keeps blinking... I don't get any prompt for username/password.

The steps are outlined below:

```sh
echo "# Python_programming_notes" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/svedagiriml/Python_programming_notes.git
git push -u origin main
```

After the `git push` command,  the cursor just keeps blinking.

I even tried to push from `master` branch, it does not work.
Kindly help.

Comment: What ide do you use? Some of them have a prompt for a username password which is not very visible. For example VS Code iirc prompts you for username password on the top of the screen. 
Btw, I suggest you set up your SSH for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest Git, check your credential helper (in charge of caching your remote credentials)

```
git config credential.helper
```

You should see manager-core (at least on Windows, but now also on Mac or Linux, as [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core`](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) is cross-platform.

Depending on your credential helper, it might trigger a popup for you to fill. Or it freezes because it is unable to display said popup (like no graphical user interface session in an headless Linux shell, [while using libsecret](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/linuxcredstores.md))

As The [OP Shivakumar Vedagiri Nagarajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16230494/shivakumar-vedagiri-nagarajan) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67981803/unable-to-push-file-from-local-repository-to-github-it-just-hangs/67982000?noredirect=1#comment120189194_67982000), a valid workaround is to use [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), which might have correctly cached the credentials in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your response Von. II did not face any issue in git push using Github Desktop. Hence i am using Github Desktop for now.

Comment: @ShivakumarVedagiriNagarajan Great! GitHub Desktop must have properly registered your credentials.

Comment: @ShivakumarVedagiriNagarajan I have edited the answer to include your comment, for more visibility.